# Create multi-dimensional array or hash in ruby from JSON

Tags: ruby, hash, popup, rhomobile

I am using Rhomobile and trying to dynamically build a hash for the id and title of the buttons has of the Alert.show_popup, but am not quite getting it.  What I want the end result to be, in effect, is:

```
  Alert.show_popup( {
    :message => 'Please Select Appropriate Address:',
    :title => 'Get Nearby...',
    :icon => :info,
    :buttons => [
      {'id' => '1', 'title' => 'Address 1'},
      {'id' => '2', 'title' => 'Address 2'},
      {'id' => '3', 'title' => 'Address 3'},
      {'id' => '4', 'title' => 'Address 4'}
    ],
    :callback => url_for(:action => :on_addressidentified_popup)
  }
  )
```

I've tried a few methods, but none have worked (build a string that looks like a hash and try_convert, etc.).  Here was the latest one I tried which seemed close, but yet still far away:

```
  nearbyaddresses = Rho::JSON.parse(@params['body'])

  h = {}

  nearbyaddresses.each do |location|
    h[intIndex] = {}
    h[intIndex][:id] = intIndex.to_s
    h[intIndex][:title] = location["Address"].to_s

    intIndex = intIndex + 1 
  end

  Alert.show_popup( {
    :message => 'Please Select Appropriate Address:',
    :title => 'Get Nearby...',
    :icon => :info,
    :buttons => h,
    :callback => url_for(:action => :on_addressidentified_popup)
  }
  )
```

Any ruby wizards here that can help me out?

Comment: Are you sure you want a hash? `buttons` is an array in your first example.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
nearby_addresses_list = Rho::JSON.parse(@params['body'])

buttons_list = nearby_addresses_list.collect.each_with_index {|address, i|
      {'id' => i, 'title' => address}  #not sure if you need to dig into this at all.
}
```

This should leave buttons_list with this value

```
[{'id' => 0, 'title' => nearby_addresses_list[0]},
{'id' => 1, 'title' => nearby_addresses_list[1]}
{'id' => 2, 'title' => nearby_addresses_list[2]}
{'id' => 3, 'title' => nearby_addresses_list[3]}]
```

If you want the id's to start with 1, change the body of the collect statement to `{'id' => i+1, 'title' => address}`

Then just add buttons_list in as the value for the key :buttons.

```
Alert.show_popup( {
    :message => 'Please Select Appropriate Address:',
    :title => 'Get Nearby...',
    :icon => :info,
    :buttons => buttons_list,
    :callback => url_for(:action => :on_addressidentified_popup)
   })
```

---

If you're seeing weirdness between the desired output you mentioned first and the code you said was close, is it perhaps that you used symbols for the keys in your code (:id), and strings in your desired output ("id") ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I addressed the issue.  Works like a charm...

```
  intIndex = 0
  nearbyaddresses = Rho::JSON.parse(@params['body'])
  @@nearbyAddresses = nearbyaddresses 

  button_array = []        

  nearbyaddresses.each do |location|
    opt = {'id' => intIndex.to_s, 'title' => location["Address"] }
    button_array << opt

    intIndex = intIndex + 1 
  end

  Alert.show_popup( {
    :message => 'Please Select Appropriate Address:', 
    :title => 'Get Nearby...', 
    :icon => :info,
    :buttons => button_array,
    :callback => url_for(:action => :getselectedaddress) 
  }
  )
```